# GKE - Error with ingress controller with externalTrafficPolicy set to Local

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a kubernetes cluster in GKE (version 1.10).

I have deployed an ingress controller with a service type `LoadBalancer`.

I have set externalTrafficPolicy to Local to retrieve the source ip in my containers.

It works well but there is a side effect: according to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-loadbalancer) only one instance is healthy and I have noticed that if I connect to an unhealty node or a container in an unhealthy node, I cannot connect to a service located in the cluster via its public dns (pointing to the load balancer ip).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean that with externalTrafficPolicy=Local, if you try to issue a request *from* a node that is not running an ingress pod, to the domain name of the load balancer, that that request will time out?

Comment: As a workaround, if you use the nginx controller it sets the `x-forwarded-for` and `x-real-ip` headers on the request

Comment: Yes @JonahBenton, and if the node is not the healthy one on the load balancer.

Comment: this is expected behavior. Traffic will not bounce from node to node, so nodes without pods will fail the LB health check

Comment: There is no reason that `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` would cause any client (including a pod in your cluster) to fail to hit your LB. Are you getting a timeout or connection refused or? Have you verified that you can hit the LB from various clients? Are you sure the DNS is working? Are you sure your firewall is allowing this traffic?